# Python requests not downloading pdf appropriately

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python 3 on Windows 10.
This is downloading a PDF that can't be opened. 136KB instead of 721KB.

I have tried the three different ways of opening the PDF and writing it to file (please see #1#, #2# and #3# in the code.

I wonder if the issue may be the authentication. I'm new to authentication, but as far as I could see the website was using POST.

```py
import requests

downloadurl = "https://pedsinreview.aappublications.org/content/pedsinreview/40/10/e35.full.pdf"

username = 'myusername'
password = 'mypassword'
chunk_size = 1024

payload = {'name': username, 'pass': password}
r = requests.get(downloadurl, data=payload, verify=False, stream=True)

#r.raw.decode_content = True
with open("file_name.pdf", 'wb') as f:
    #1#f.write(r.content)
    #2#shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)  
    #3#for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size):
        #3#if chunk:
            #3#f.write(chunk)
```

Expected output of a 721 KB PDF I can open, but I get a 136KB file that can't be read.

Thank you in advance for any help.

---

UPDATE:

WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!

```py
import requests

loginurl = "https://pedsinreview.aappublications.org/user/login"
downloadurl = "https://pedsinreview.aappublications.org/content/pedsinreview/40/10/e35.full.pdf"

username = 'myusername'
password = 'mypassword'
chunk_size = 1024

#r = requests.get(downloadurl, data=payload, verify=False, stream=True)

# Do everything with the context of the session
with requests.Session() as session:
    data = {
        'form_id': 'user_login',
        'name': username,
        'pass': password
    }
    login_request = session.post(loginurl, data=data)
    print(login_request.status_code) # returns 200, I think it should be 302 because 
    #that's what it shows when I login successfully in browser vs. 200 when I use a 
    #wrong password.

    # Now you are logged in and should be able to request the pdf
    r = session.get(downloadurl)

with open("file_name.pdf", 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size):
        if chunk:
            f.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Because the link is not a direct link to the pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about it being an authentication issue. Since you're not logged in, the server redirects you to an html page, which is what you're getting.

So first thing, you'll want to do something along the lines of:

```
# Do everything with the context of the session
with requests.Session() as session:
    # Not sure if the last few are required, but I went to the site and looked at 
    # the login request and this is everything that was included.
    data = {
        'name': 'myusername',
        'pass': 'mypassword',
        'form_id': 'highwire_user_login',
        'form_build_id': 'form-yXL7wQkB-M6s7VkeYYQMBr0lPt8ICKc1ZFB5Qc-bOJ4'
        'op': 'Log in'
    }
    login_request = session.post("https://pedsinreview.aappublications.org/content/40/10/e35", data=data)
    print(login_request.status_code) # should be 200
    # Now you are logged in and should be able to request the pdf
    r = requests.get(downloadurl, verify=False, stream=True)
    ...
```